# pandas read_table with regex delimiter, since negative numbers don't have intervening whitespace

Tags: python, regex, pandas, number-formatting

I am trying to read a space separated table (sample below) into a pandas dataframe using the `read_table` function.

```
1  0.00000E+00-7.52896E-04 0.00000E+00 0.00000E+00 0.00000E+00 0.00000E+00 0.00000E+00 0.00000E+00 0.00000E+00 0.00000E+00 1.00247E-01 0.00000E+00
9  2.57945E+00-9.98377E-04 0.00000E+00 1.80923E+02 0.00000E+00 0.00000E+00 1.08995E+03 0.00000E+00 0.00000E+00 1.00795E+01 1.00002E-01 0.00000E+00
18  2.37285E+00-2.20000E-01 0.00000E+00 1.81079E+02-5.53001E+00 0.00000E+00 1.30827E+03 2.01207E+03 0.00000E+00 9.87285E+00 8.64615E-01 0.00000E+00
```

The problem, however is that the negative values appear without a delimeter e.g.

```
1.81079E+02-5.53001E+00
```

The following two options do not generate the desired output:

```
t=pds.read_table(filepath, sep='\s+|\d\-\d', engine='python')

t=pds.read_table(filepath, sep='(\s+|\d\-\d)', engine='python')
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: are the row numbers actually included in your table? You might get better luck with [`read_fwf()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_fwf.html) as your file appears to have fixed width columns

Comment: Thanks for this tip @asongtoruin, yes the row numbers are included but I can exclude them if that is possible at all. Another issue is that there are two different tables (with different number of columns but same number of rows) that alternately repeat throughout the file (I know the number of repetitions though). Also there are headers for both tables as well as some other text in between. Would read_fwf() work then? I will try meanwhile, nonetheless.

Comment: What's your goal for the locations where you have "two different tables"? Do you want the two different layouts going into two different dataframes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may first add spaces before the negative values with

```
file_contents = re.sub(r'(\d)(-\d*\.)', r'\1 \2', file_contents)
```

It matches

- `(\d)` - Group 1: a digit
- `(-\d*\.)` - Group 2: a hyphen and then 0+ digits followed with a period.
- `\1` and `\2` are placeholders that reference the values stored in Group 1 and 2 memory buffers from the replacement pattern (thus, Group 1 and 2 values are pasted back into the resulting string).

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pl5INK/5).

Then, you may use the `r'\s+'` regex as a `sep` value to read the table.

Comment: Ah didn't see this reply. Thanks so much, this is very close to what I need - except that eats the negative sign. Could you kindly update to fix this issue?

Comment: I mean can I keep the negative sign with the number after splitting?

Comment: Then, you can't use `split` because Python `re` does not split with empty strings. Can you *match* instead? Then you may use [`-?\d*\.?\d+(?:[eE][-+]?\d+)?`](https://regex101.com/r/pl5INK/4)

Comment: I guess not, can I instead add a pre-processing step to the file where I match and then add a space before the negative sign, save the file and re-read using read_table?

Comment: @Kam So, you need to pre-process the input file first.

Comment: @Kam I added the code you need. Please read the file and save it using your favorite module. It might be preferable to read and write line by line, though from my current experience using AWS servers with `HugeFiles=on` I do not see any problem with a mere read-replace-write operation.

Comment: Did the job for me ... thanks ... a small typo, the closing ' is missing in r'(\d)(-\d*\.)